# How to remove the error of 'can only concatenate str (not "float") to str' in Python while returning a string?

Tags: python, string, data-structures, integer

I am trying to calculate a percentage of landmass occupied by a country from the total landmass.I am taking two arguments as string and float in a function and returning String along with the calculated percentage in it. For example the **Input =area_of_country("Russia", 17098242)** and **Output = "Russia is 11.48% of the total world's landmass"**. Below is my code

```
    class Solution(object):

    def landmass(self, st, num):
        percentage = 148940000 / num * 100

        return st + "is" + percentage + "of total world mass!"


if __name__ == "__main__":

    s = "Russia"
    n = 17098242
    print(Solution().landmass(s, n))
```

Error :-

```
        return st + "is" + percentage + "of total world mass!"
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the percentage (since it's a float) into a string when concatenating using the + operator. So your return statement would look like:

```
return str(st) + "is" + str(percentage) + "of total world mass!"
```

Comment: Is there any built in library for rounding off the decimals to two decimals only?

Comment: @Aurora19 You can use the round function:
`round(percentage, 2)`

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

> return st + "is" + percentage + "of total world mass!"

Try this:

```
return str(st) + "is" + str(percentage) + "of total world mass!"
```

Comment: How to round to two decimals if I have to ?

Comment: You can use `round` function. eg: `round(answer, 2)`

Comment: When I use round function it's completely removing the decimals. I want decimals but up to two digits only